# Finding all methods that uses a specific method directly or indirectly in native c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-analysis, call-hierarchy

Is there any tool for discovering all direct or indirect method usage for a specific method in  c++. For managed classes NDepend does the job "Select method that are using me", however I am struggled how to do it in native classes. Visual Studio's call hierarchy can generate results like that, however it doesnt scale in our huge code base. I would like to have a report generated automatically. I am wondering if you guys can suggest some tool.

Comment: SO people don't seem to like requests for tools (not my policy, I'm just telling you).  You might consider asking your question at Software Recommendations.  Make sure you read the rules about posing a query.

Answer (score 4):

Since your using ndepend, what about it's sister product [cppdepend](http://www.cppdepend.com).

Comment: nice tool. Unfortunately it crashed with our huge sln file.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen is a software documentation system which can be run in batch.

if CALLER_GRAPH is set to YES, a graphical caller graph is drawn for each function showing the functions that the function is directly or indirectly called by.

It is used for large sources and can be run on windows.

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't resolve inheritance, overloaded operators or indirect function pointers.  Has that changed?